# How many records/tables could I have in a 1gb database?

Tags: sql-server, record

I'm thinking about buying a shared hosting provider, and then offer a 1GB MSSQL database with the package.

**This may not be an exact science**, but how many records/tables can I save in a 1GB database? I will be saving pure text (*meaning: nvarchar, varchar, int, bool*) and not binaries/blobs.

For this question, imagine around 20 tables, with 9 fields each. Not null on every field.

Is there some way to gauge and project how long this will hold me over before I need to upgrade to a more expensive package?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: Thanks that's clear it up for me. /s

Comment: This one has no real answer except: Install SQL Server Express, insert test rows and measure the size.

Comment: Some times experienced user feel that a question is too naive, like a master archer will feel if a student asks do i need to pull the string back to shoot the arrow? But yes its a good question and is more relevant when you have to make choice of managed db or self hosted at very early stage of learning

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no real answer that tells you 'set amount' of 'records and/or tables' is the maximum that you can hold in a 1 GB MSSQL database, or when you'll reach that point. There are several factors to look at when estimating:

1. What do you believe is the average row going to be taking up?
2. Will you be using fixed or variable?
3. How frequent is content going to be added and removed?

In the end, you're looking at (for example) a maximum amount of rows that could be < 400 000 rows or > 3 500 000, it all comes down to what you put in a single row and what types you're using. Once you have decided what a single row will be (give or take) and how many rows you're expecting to be added/frequency, you can determine how long you'll be able to go without upgrading to another database package.

Answer (score 1):

I think E.J. Brennan was being sarcastic - it's a bit like "How long is a piece of string?"

It depends on how big your records are, and if your schema allocates a fixed or variable amount of memory for each string.

Comment: Yes, I was...I didn't even think the question was real, at least not in its original form...

Answer (score 1):

That is one very good question.
It depends on a lot of things, number of tables, rows, what is in them and so on.

edit: okay you made an edit.
"For this question, imagine around 20 tables, with 9 fields each. Not null on every field."
1 database, 20 tables, 9 fields each, varchar (16) we say.

i would say about 300.000 (300K) rows total, but it depends on type of database structure (innoDB or other kinds)